# Need to configure a Spring AOP Advice within an AspectJ project

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj, spring-aop

I've got a Spring project that uses AspectJ.  In 99.9% of the cases, using AspectJ (ajc) to CTW my aspects is working as expected.

However, in one particular situation, I find I am needed to weave my aspect around a Spring aspect.  More specifically, I want to wrap a Spring @Transactional.

If I use AspectJ ajc to CTW my advice, it will weave it around any method that is defined as @Transactional.  Rather, I want to wrap the Spring @Transactional advice.  Basically, I am trying to catch any errors that are thrown within a Transaction and retry the transaction if failed.

My problem is that by already using ajc in the rest of the project, it automatically weaves in my aspect into my classes, rather than allowing Spring's AOP mechanisms to interpret it and weave it at run time.

My project is using the `aspectj-maven-plugin`.  How do I configure my pom/project such that ajc ignores my @Aspect, but Spring still sees it?

Comment: And why wouldn't you be able to do that with AspectJ itself? Also why not simply use the spring-retry project which already provides this advice/aspect..

Comment: @M.Deinum I have been unable to get AspectJ to behave properly. :)  I had presumed it was b/c AspectJ was working against the class files and any methods annotated with `@Transactional` were getting woven, as opposed to the calling Transactional aspect (which is where I really need the try/catch).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've looked for the spring-retry project, but have been unable to find it on the spring.io site.  The closest thing I found was something on github, but wasn't sure if that was stable or not.  Ironically, I did find documentation for it on the spring.io site (http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/) which confuses me even more since it has been pulled out from the spring-batch project.

Comment: @EricB. did you figure it out ?

Comment: @Adams.H Frankly, I don't remember.  If I had, I would certainly have updated my post which leads me to believe that I approached the problem differently instead.  In retrospect, I think I could have excluded the given aspect from the ajc compiler and used a different execution to point specifically to the Spring class(es) that I was trying to target.

Answer (score 1):

> My project is using the aspectj-maven-plugin. How do I configure my
>   pom/project such that ajc ignores my @Aspect, but Spring still sees
>   it?

Don't include the Spring aspect library.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>${project.javaVersion}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <!-- remove this -->
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
```

Having both compile time weaving and run time proxy-based AOP is probably more trouble than it's worth and is likely to introduce other issues.  It shouldn't be a problem to have both your aspect and the standard Sping aspect advise @Transactional methods.  If I were you'd I'd stick with compile time weaving and [set the precedence](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html#advice-precedence) on your aspect so that it is run first.  Within your aspect, you can catch exceptions and retry as needed.

From the AspectJ docs:

> A piece of around advice controls whether advice of lower precedence
>   will run by calling proceed. The call to proceed will run the advice
>   with next precedence, or the computation under the join point if there
>   is no further advice.
>
> A piece of before advice can prevent advice of lower precedence from
>   running by throwing an exception. If it returns normally, however,
>   then the advice of the next precedence, or the computation under the
>   join pint if there is no further advice, will run.